# Apply stylesheet to half a page with shadow-dom?

Tags: css, shadow-dom

Can I apply an external stylesheet to a specific div/element with shadow-dom or via any other means? I've heard about shadow-dom and I *believe* it lets you constrain your styles, but that's about all I know.

Specifically, I want half the page to use bootstrap, and the other half to use MUI or something else. This is just to show how my library works nicely with different themes.

I don't want to modify the CSS in anyway to constrain it to a specific element, nor do I want to use iframes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can apply an external stysheet in a Shadow DOM using the `@import url` CSS rule.

```
div.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
   .innerHTML = `
       <style>
           @import url( './external-style.css' )
       </style>
       <!-- other elements -->`
```

*NB*: The `@import` rule must placed at the top of the `<style>` element.

You can then manipulate the Shadow DOM like a normal DOM:

```
div.shadowRoot.appendChild( firstSection.cloneNode( true ) )
```

---

If your content is already existing in the normal DOM, you can move it with `appendChild()`, duplicate it with `cloneNode()` as in the above example), or *reveal* it with the help of `<slot>` element:

```js
div1.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
div1.shadowRoot.innerHTML = `
  <style>
    :host { display: inline ; background: #cfc ; }
    ::slotted( span ) { color: red ; }
  </style>
  <slot></slot>`
```

```html
<div id=div1>
    <span>Hello</span> world
</div>
```

In the last case you'll need to use the `::slotted` pseudo-element to change the style of the original DOM, so maybe you'll have to modify already existing stylesheet. The best solution depends on your use case.

Comment: Can you not put existing content into the shadow DOM without moving (like via appendChild)? Moving elements around breaks React.

Comment: Those slots are really weird, but I think they might work for what I'm trying to do! It's unfortunate that I can't `@import` an external stylesheet this way, but I guess I can copy it into my project; will just make maintaining it harder. Thank you for your help!